# How to add fonts for latest version of react native that uses CLI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-cli

I know how to add fonts to react-native linking assets. Now I am using the latest version of react-native `0.61.5` and I am not able to link assets.

Do I still need to use `react-native link` in such a case. If I use `react-native link`, It may cause issues to the already linked modules or the modules that need not be linked using `react-native link`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Root folder called `assets` and `fonts` folder inside with your own `.ttf` files inside.

Edit `react-native.config.js` from the root of the project. If you don't have it, create it.

inside the file you should have something like this.

```
module.exports = {   
  project: {
    ios: {},
    android: {}, // grouped into "project"
  },
  assets: ["./assets/fonts"], // stays the same 
};
```

after save, run:

> react-native link